Sitecore 8.2 Analytics Filter values not populating
I am using Sitecore 8.2 and facing issues while running Experience Analytics.
When I select Audience -> Overview, the report does not show up and filters are blank:

The console has following exception:

If I select Acquisition -> Overview, values in the filter dropdown are populated fine, the report loads fine and no exception in console.
Any idea why this must be happening? Analytics is not my forte but I have been asked to look into this one.
Thanks in advance!
